# Use Views to wrap large passages of text into 32700 character chunks

Tags: views

I am using Views to create an XML feed. The body portion of the xml is wrapped in specialized `<text>` tags. I need to break up this body text into chunks of 32700 characters each and wrap them each in `<text>` tags.

I know I can easily trim the body to 32700 characters in Views, but I then need to display the overflow text in another block of `<text>`.

Comment: This would be easiest in a views tpl. Have you ever done that before?

Comment: No, I haven't. I mainly do site-builder functions in Drupal not usually PHP, but I can start if you might be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Answer added below. If you have any questions, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, if you click `Theme: Information` under `Advanced`, you'll get a lot of tpl.php file names that you can use.

For this view called `Output Test`, we can see the below under information for the field `Body`.

```
Field Content: Body (ID: body): views-view-field.tpl.php, 
views-view-field--body.tpl.php, 
views-view-field--output-test.tpl.php, 
views-view-field--output-test--body.tpl.php, 
views-view-field--page.tpl.php, views-view-field--page--body.tpl.php
```

We can see the first one is called `views-view-field.tpl.php` and that is the file we can find in our `modules/views/theme` folder. We have to copy that to anywhere in our theme folder and then rename it to the most relevant tpl.php listed in our view's Information.

For this example, that's `views-view-field--output-test--body.tpl.php`

At this point, after copying the file to your theme folder and renaming it appropriately, you can clear cache so Drupal will know to look for it. Seriously, do this. It's infuriating working on something when Drupal doesn't even know to look for your work.

This file has `<?php print $output; ?>` as what we would usually print in our view. A basic example of outputting every 32700 characters between `<text></text>` tags is below.

```
<?php 
    $split = str_split($output, 32700);
    $joined = implode('</text><text>', $split);
    print '<text>'. $joined . '</text>'; 
?>
```

What the above does is split your output, re-implode and finally add the outer tags.

I have no idea of the exact output of your XML feed so you need to look up the appropriate PHP from here. If the text is already wrapped in  tags because of the view, just `print $joined;` or something.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm not getting that to work. I have confirmed the views-view-field--output-test--body.tpl.php template is being recognized by views for the body field. The <text> wrappers are being created by the field label, so I wonder if I need to either add this code to the views field loop template or somehow target the  $field->label_html?

Comment: In your field's settings, Try disabling `Style Settings>Add default classes` and enable `Rewrite Results>Strip HTML tags`. There are so many little options to get it right. You could also disable the label add it manually in the tpl or something. Trial and error.

Comment: Hmm..both of those things were already done...I am wondering if I actually need to call the array of the field more specifically as is indicated here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views/theming-a-single-field-in-a-views-3-template Unfortunately, that support doc ends right at the array part!

Comment: Only saw this now. Have you made any progress? Perhaps paste in some output for us to work with.

Comment: Well, some but not much. I can confirm that I am now able to manipulate the output of that field by more specifically targeting the field id and array: `$str = $row->field_body[0]['raw']['value'];` but I have tried to break up the output of that field by using chunklen, chunk_split, and wordwrap without much luck.